# Problem Of re-rendring the component and using memo()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

The problem is when I update the quantity of an item the parent component start to re-render again I want to understand what am doing wrong I already using memo to stop doing the re-render so what should i do if i wanna fix the re-render and only update the object on array with out re-rendring, if somebody can help me with that?
Thanks in advance

**Parent Component**

```
export const ProductsScreen = ({ }) => {
    const [Products, setProducts] = useState([
       // sample of object props
        {
            id: '1',
            name: 'first item',
            volume: 500,
            price: 150.25,
            total: 4,
            qty: 0
        }]


    const renderProducts = ({ item }) => {
        const { qty } = item
        return (
            <ProductListItems
                product={item}
                qty={qty}
                onAddItem={onAddItem}
                onRemoveItem={onRemoveItem} />
        )
    }


    const updateObjectInArray = (newProduct) => {
        return setProducts(
            Products.map((item) => {
                if (item.id !== newProduct.id) {
                    return item
                }
                return {
                    ...item,
                    ...newProduct
                }
            })
        )
    }

    const onAddItem = productId => {
        let product = Products.find(i => {
            return i.id === productId
        })
        const { total, qty } = product
        const newProduct = {
            ...product,
            qty: qty + 1,
            total: total - 1
        }
        updateObjectInArray(newProduct)
    }

    const onRemoveItem = productId => {
        let product = Products.find(i => {
            return i.id === productId
        })
        const { total, qty } = product
        const newProduct = {
            ...product,
            qty: qty - 1,
            total: total + 1
        }
        updateObjectInArray(newProduct)
    }

    return (
        console.log("RERENDERD"),
        <View style={styles.container} >
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, }}>
                <FlatList
                    contentContainerStyle={{ paddingVertical: 15 }}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    data={Products}
                    renderItem={renderProducts}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />
            </SafeAreaView>
        </View >
    )
};
```

**Child Component**

```
const ProductListItems = ({
    product,
    qty,
    onAddItem,
    onRemoveItem
}) => {
    return (
        // design here
    )
};

export default memo(ProductListItems, (prevState, nextState) => prevState.qty === nextState.qty);
```

Comment: I assume you change using `setProducts` and that changes products so ProductsScreen will re render but it should only re render the item that changed if item is a pure component (React.memo)

Comment: what you suggest to do exactly on setProducts i dont get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handlers add and remove are only created on mount using React.useCallback because there are no dependencies, using the callback to the state setter to prevent a dependency on products.

The renderItem prop has to be a [function that returns jsx](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#required-renderitem) but since `ProductListItems` is a pure component it won't re render as long as props didn't change. Not sure how FlatList works but this should prevent each item from rendering if only one item changed.

```js
const { useState, useCallback, memo } = React;
//just for this demo, naive implementation of FlatList
const FlatList = memo(function FlatList({
  data,
  renderItem,
  keyExtractor,
}) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map((item) => {
        //strange need for renderItem to be a function that
        //  returns jsx but let's roll with it I'm sure there
        //  is a good reason for it
        const content = renderItem({ item });
        return (
          <div key={keyExtractor(item)}>{content}</div>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
});
//Make sure this component is pure so it won't re create jsx
//  even if you didn't use memo the handlers would not cause
//  a DOM re render (not sure about native)
const ProductListItems = memo(function ProductListItems({
  product,
  // removed qty, it is in product
  onAddItem,
  onRemoveItem,
}) {
  console.log(
    'render ProductListItems for id:',
    product.id
  );
  return (
    <li>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(product, undefined, 2)}</pre>
      <button onClick={() => onAddItem(product.id)}>
        Add
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => onRemoveItem(product.id)}>
        Remove
      </button>
    </li>
  );
});
//this is the code you could use, I removed some jsx but logic
//  should be re usable
const ProductsScreen = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      total: 4,
      qty: 0,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      total: 6,
      qty: 0,
    },
  ]);
  //when products change this render is
  //  needed but does not have to cause
  //  all items to be re rendered
  console.log('render products screen');

  //only create this function on mount so
  //  it won't re render all items
  //  passing a new handler to a sub component
  //  will cause virtual DOM compare to fail
  //  and React will re render that DOM
  const changeQty = useCallback(
    (direction) => (productId) =>
      setProducts(
        //use callback to state setter to prevent
        //  Products to be a dependency
        (products) =>
          products.map((product) =>
            product.id !== productId
              ? product
              : {
                  ...product,
                  qty: product.qty + direction,
                  //had a logical error on next line (fixed now)
                  total: product.total + direction * -1,
                }
          )
      ),
    []
  );
  //both handlers depend on changeQty but that is only created
  //  on mount
  const onAddItem = useCallback(changeQty(1), [changeQty]);
  const onRemoveItem = useCallback(changeQty(-1), [
    changeQty,
  ]);
  //FlatList renderItem has to be a function
  //  https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#required-renderitem
  //  no need to memoize anything as ProductListItems is a pure
  //  component
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <ProductListItems
      product={item}
      onAddItem={onAddItem}
      onRemoveItem={onRemoveItem}
    />
  );

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={products}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    />
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <ProductsScreen />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: amazing bro thank you, 
you make my skills level up Really thank you

Comment: one only thing we can't use 

renderItem={renderProducts(
              onAddItem,
              onRemoveItem
            )}
cause render product is intance am thinking how to solve now if you got it ping me up

Comment: @Jack I updated my answer, if I have a correct understanding of how FlatList works this should not render all items if only one changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 **FlatList is a built-in list on react native** 

import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

const DATA = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
];



const App = () => {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    return(
          <Item title={item.title} />
       )
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```